# Getting a route parameter in class that extends Request

Tags: laravel, parameters, request

Let's say I have a route:

```php
Route::get('.../{abc}/...', [
  'uses' => 'API\SomeApiController@progress'
]);
```

The `SomeApiController::progress()` method gets the object `ApiRequest` as an argument:

```php
public function progress(ApiRequest $request, $abc)
```

How can I get the value of `abc` in the `ApiRequest::authorize()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the request object, use the [`route`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L774-L790) method:

```php
$abc = $this->route('abc');
```